# Is there any way to find out which specific algorithms are used in Microsoft's implementation of C++ library?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Does anyone know which, or know of any way to find out which, algorithms are used in Microsoft's implementation of the C++ standard library? Is it just private information?

I don't doubt that they're using algorithms which guarantee the performance requirements specified in the C++ standard for STL containers etc. but I'd be very interested to know the specifics!

Thanks!

Comment: You can open up the headers and take a peek, it's almost all there.

Comment: (It should also be noted that in most cases, the standard all but tells an implementation what algorithm they must use in their requirements. There are a couple of exceptions (e.g. `map` can be either red black trees or AVL trees) but there aren't many.

Comment: MSVC used to come with the source for the standard library.  Does it not do that any more?  It used to be licensed to Microsoft from DinkumWare http://www.dinkum.com/

Comment: Just in case anyone needs this, here are the bug fixes for VC5 and VC6 versions of the STL: https://web.archive.org/web/20101230021335/http://www.dinkumware.com/vc_fixes.html  (Actually, you should just upgrade your compiler...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nearly all the code in the standard library is implemented as headers since the templates have to be available in every source file that uses them. Just open up the headers and have a look.

Also, there is a great video series direct from MS that covers a lot of the implementation details of the STL.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL

Answer (score 0):

Jerry Jeremiah is correct, MSVC uses the DinkumWare libraries.  If you want more information I highly recommend the STL lectures.